# Can I automate SoapUI with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, soapui

Lots of folks have found SoapUI to be a very useful tool. We're checking it out now. But their support page / articles are weak.

Does anyone here have any experience automating SoapUI with C#? I've seen some sample code that appears to be calling SoapUI components from C# and am wondering what hoops I need to jump through -- what references I need -- to accomplish that.

To clarify, I'm wondering about creating a .NET/C# app that calls SoapUI objects and methods.

Comment: SoapUI is a Java application. There are libraries that will allow you to do it, but it is *dark magic*.

Comment: Can you provide more context?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish with SoapUI, and why are you interested in automating it with C#?

Comment: I've been tasked with creating a framework where non-coding testers can submit English worded instructions (test cases) to test REST APIs (product) and I want to also create a fuzzer which will generate its own tests. I would prefer to create a .Net/C# app to do this -- seems relatively easy to me.

But someone suggested using SoapUI for this test framework. So now we are investigating SoapUI as a vehicle for automating these REST API that need to be tested.

I'm new to SoapUI and I can see that it is quite rich. One question is, can I create an app in .Net/C# that might call into SoapUI. THX!

Comment: @user2438277 : Were you able to find some references or solution? If so, could you please share?

Comment: Me too!. I am trying to find something similar to http://www.mbtest.org/ but for soap

Answer (score 1):

I hate suggesting you an alternative, because it's not a real answer to your question. But are there things you look for in SoapUI you can't do with Curl? Curl is easy to automate (it even has a NuGet package).

Comment: With Curl, can I stand up a SOAP service test double based on a WSDL definition? What I want to do is build an automated integration test harness for our distributed system. I need to be able to intercept and interrogate SOAP requests made by the various components to ensure correct overall behavior.

Comment: Curl is shell executed, not matter the platform. So the short answer is yes. For the simple reason that curl allows you to basically do any form of http request and then pipe it to another application.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I don't want to make a http request, I want to receive one. The system under test will make the call, I need to inspect the call.

Comment: Ah right. In that case (but not knowing your situation) I'd probably release a microservice somewhere, running on nginx, written in node.js. All free, all multi-platform (which is good because linux is also free(-ish)) and very lightweight. Then again, if you just need it for development purposes, you can do that with SOAPUI using mocking services, like so: https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/working-with-mockservices.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However I need to be able to stand up the call interception as part of the test set up. I don't believe soapui has a command line or anythinig to do this.

Comment: I think you're correct, SOAPUI would not be suitable for that. You may want to take a look a containerizing the setup I mentioned above, it's very easy: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/